# innerHTML passing variables as parameters in onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have to pass a variable as a parameter in a onclick event using innerHTML. Here's my code

```
var seriesdel = document.getElementById('series_name').value;
document.getElementById('all_series').innerHTML +="<p>"+document.getElementById('series_name').value+" <button class='button' id='delete' onclick='deleteseries("+seriesdel+");' value='Delete'>Delete</button></p>";
```

As you see, I try to pass the variable "seriesdel" in the function "deleteseries" but I just can't make it works.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Look at the generated code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are trying to pass a string object, you need to escape your string in the onclick function call:
`onclick='deleteseries(\""+seriesdel+"\");'`

Comment: Thank's ! Works perfectly now !

Answer (score 3):

Form control values are strings.

When you want to stick a string value in JavaScript you have to surround it with quotes.

You have omitted the quotes, so whatever is typed into the input will (unless it is a number) be treated as either a variable name or a syntax error.

Add the quotes.

---

Trying to deal with JavaScript embedded in HTML embedded in JavaScript (which is probably embedded in HTML) will give you a headache. Use DOM instead. It is more verbose, but a lot clearer.

```
var seriesdel = document.getElementById('series_name').value;
var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(seriesdel));
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.classList.add("button");
button.setAttribute("id", "delete");
button.value = "Delete";
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
button.addEventListener("click", deleteHandler);
paragraph.appendChild(button);
document.getElementById('all_series').appendChild(paragraph);

function deleteHandler(event) {
    deleteseries(seriesdel);
}
```